# "Find top 5 queries" by date

Tags: sql-server, azure, sql-server-2012, azure-sql-database

How do I run the query below (from [this MSDN article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/ff394114.aspx)) to determine the top worst queries (by CPU time) **but only for a set date?**

```
-- Find top 5 queries
SELECT TOP 5 query_stats.query_hash AS "Query Hash", 
    SUM(query_stats.total_worker_time) / SUM(query_stats.execution_count) AS "Avg CPU Time",
    MIN(query_stats.statement_text) AS "Statement Text"
FROM 
    (SELECT QS.*, 
    SUBSTRING(ST.text, (QS.statement_start_offset/2) + 1,
    ((CASE statement_end_offset 
        WHEN -1 THEN DATALENGTH(st.text)
        ELSE QS.statement_end_offset END 
            - QS.statement_start_offset)/2) + 1) AS statement_text
     FROM sys.dm_exec_query_stats AS QS
     CROSS APPLY sys.dm_exec_sql_text(QS.sql_handle) as ST) as query_stats
GROUP BY query_stats.query_hash
ORDER BY 2 DESC;
GO
```

Our database has just gone under serious strain in the last day and we cannot figure out the source of the problem.

We are using Azure SQL Database.

Comment: You can filter on the `query_stats.last_execution_time`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not possible to get statistics per day from the DMVs. dm_exec_query_stats has columns creation_time and last_execution_time which of course can give you some idea what has happened -- but that's only the first and last time that plan was used. The statistics will also be lost if the plan gets dropped out of plan cache, so you might not have that plan and its statistics anymore if the situation is now better (and the "bad" plans have been replaced by better ones).

That query shows the average CPU used by the queries, so it's not the perfect query for solving performance problems, because it really is average, so something with small execution count can be really high in the list even if it's really not a problem. I usually use total CPU and total logical reads for solving performance issues -- but those are total amounts since creation time, which might be a long time ago. In that case you might also considering dividing the numbers with hours since the creation time, so you'll get average CPU / I/O per hour. Also looking at max* columns might give some hints for the bad queries / plans.

If you have this kind of problems it might be a good idea to schedule that SQL as a task and gather the results somewhere. Then you can also use it as a baseline for comparing what has changed when the situation is bad. Of course in that case (and probably also otherwise) you should most likely look at more than just the top 5.